# php short if statements problem

Tags: php, logic

i'm trying to do many checks and i found out if i use the short if statement i would produce a shorter code and it would reduce my script by about 100 line

```
if (($options['vss_check'] == 'all' ? 
     check_facebook() && check_plusone() : 
     ($options['vss_check'] == 'fbonly' ? 
       check_facebook() : 
       ($options['vss_check'] == 'poonly' ? 
         check_plusone()
       )
     )
   ) &&!is_null( $content ) &&!is_feed() ) {
```

however i get a syntax error 'unexpected )' on that line
what did i do wrong ?
thank you

Comment: O_O Shorter? Maybe. Comprehensible? Absolutely not.

Comment: I would click `blame/show annotations` instantly if I encounter this code in a project. This roars the fire inside.

Comment: That's why people are suposed to write __readable__ and __comprehensible__ code - because one day they may need to post it to SO! Moreover, when properly laid out, these kinds of problems usually become obvious.

Comment: who said i want people to see my code ? i'm doing this to harden the thing ;)

Comment: You know you'd have to edit this yourself in a while. Don't cut yourself in your hand! Run your code trough an tokenizer of some sort when publishing if you need it to be unreadable...

Comment: @Blagovest what attitude ? should i lie about my intention to make the code hard to read ?, and i didn't make this to harden it (just a side effect) i did this to remove a 100 line of repeated code as said in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should avoid this, because it makes your code much harder to read and to debug.

Your error is where you have

```
($options['vss_check'] == 'poonly' ? check_plusone() )
```

It is missing the `:` and the value if the condition is false.

Comment: yes thats it, let me fix another bug and i'll mark it as solved

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that you've realised by now that putting everything on one line makes it difficult to match brackets and make sure your code is correct. This is very bad practice: you should make your code as readable as possible, not fit on as few lines as possible.

Having said that, by laying your code out a tiny bit more sensibly, I get

```
if (
    ($options['vss_check'] == 'all' ? check_facebook() && check_plusone() :
        ($options['vss_check'] == 'fbonly' ? check_facebook() :
            ($options['vss_check'] == 'poonly' ? check_plusone())))
    && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
{
```

From here I can see that the final ternary operator has no `:` part... changing that line to

```
            ($options['vss_check'] == 'poonly' ? check_plusone() : )))
```

should work. But I don't recommend you stop there: this code needs laying out more sensibly.